# Find the longest sequence length whose sum is divisible by 3

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, time-complexity

I have an exercise that needs to be done with O(n) time complexity, however, I can only solve it with an O(n^2) solution.

You have an array and you need to count the longest contiguous sequence such that it's sum can be divided to 3 without any remainder. For example for `array {1,2,3,-4,-1)`, the function will return 4 because the longest sequence that its `sum(0)` can be divided to `3` is `{2,3,-4,-1}`.

My solution O(n^2) is based on **`arithmetic progression`**. Is there any way to do it with O(n) complexity?

Please, I only want a clue or a theoretical explanation. Please don't write the full solution :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's take a look at prefix sums. A `[L, R]` subarray is divisble by 3 if and only if 
`prefixSum[L - 1] mod 3 = prefixSum[R] mod 3`. This observation gives a very simple linear solution(because there are only 3 possible values of a prefix sum mod 3, we can simply find the first and the last one).

For example, if the input array is {1, 2, 3, -4, -1}, the prefix sums are {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1}. (there are n + 1 prefix sums because of an empty prefix). Now you can just take a look at the first and last occurrence of 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: can you give me an example with an array with values ?

Comment: If i understood correctly, i need to find the max between (first zero -> last zero), (first 1 -> last 1), (first 2 -> last 2) and fi

Comment: Why there is an extra empty prefix?

Comment: Also, how you concluded that a subarray `[L, R]` is divisible by 3  if `prefixSum[L - 1] mod 3 = prefixSum[R] mod 3`?

Comment: As for why there is an "extra" prefix sum - consider the array with two values. There are two values, but three possible places to break the array in: before the first value, between the two values, and after the second value. For an array of length `n` there will be `n+1` sub-arrays or prefix sums.

Comment: @haccks sum[L, R] mod 3 = 0 <=> (prefixSum[R] - prefixSum[L - 1]) mod 3 = 0 <=> prefixSum[R] mod 3 = prefixSum[L - 1] mod 3.

Comment: @ILoveCoding; Got it. Now tell me about "empty prefix"?

Comment: @haccks if L = 0(in 0-based indexing), then we need a value for L - 1. It is outside the bounds of an array, even though a range [0, something] is valid. That's why need to add an empty prefix(to avoid handling this case separately). It is just a convenient way to say prefixSum[-1] = 0.

Comment: @ILoveCoding; Yeah. I just figured it out. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @bartzy The output is 1 and it is correct. {0} is divisible by 3.

Comment: @kraskevich You really should edit your answer and mention that after calculating the prefix sum you are also doing a mod 3 on that sum. Otherwise its very confusing as to how you are calculating your prefix sums.

Answer (score 3):

As a non-CS person, this is interesting. First approach of mine was simply to calc the running sum mod 3. You'll get a sequence of {0,1,2}. Now look for the first and the last 0, the first and the last 1 and the first and the last 2, and compare their respective distances...

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through the array, summing the total as you go. Record the position of the first position where the modulo sum is `0`. Also, record the position of he first position where the modulo sum is `1`. And, finally, record the position of he first position where the modulo sum is `2`.

Do the same thing backwards also, recording the last position where the modulo sum is `0`, `1`, and `2`.  That gives three possibilities for the longest sequence - you just check which pair are farthest apart.

Answer (score 2):

You apply dynamic programming.
For every position you compute 3 values:

- The longest sequence ending in that position which has sum s = 0 mod 3
- The longest sequence ending in that position which has sum s = 1 mod 3
- The longest sequence ending in that position which has sum s = 2 mod 3

So given this value for position i you can easily compute the new ones for position i+1.

Comment: but if you calc for each position those 3 values you need to do it with two loops doesnt you ? and that O(n^2) time complexity

Comment: No. You can update those 3 values in constant time for every position.

Comment: The solution`s time complaxity will be 6N ?